# Phonegap android adding file plugin build fail

Tags: android, cordova

I start with a new phonegap project.

I added android to the project a i build it. No error.

Then i added only the file plugin and build it again. Now im getting this error

can someone help me with this!

this is the output from the terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Jurrid:~ jurrid$ cd MOR
MacBook-Pro-van-Jurrid:MOR jurrid$ cordova build
[Error: An error occurred while building the android project. Warning : [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debug
Cleaning project...
Buildfile: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /Users/jurrid/adt-bundle/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MOR
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/gen
[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
[getlibpath] No Libraries
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Buildfile: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3
 [checkenv] Installed at /Users/jurrid/adt-bundle/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MOR
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MOR...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MOR...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 15 source files to /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/bin/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/ContentFilesystem.java:154: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             metadata.put("type", resourceApi.getMimeType(inputURL.URL));
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getMimeType(Uri)
    [javac]   location: variable resourceApi of type CordovaResourceApi
    [javac] Note: /Users/jurrid/MOR/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/DirectoryManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jurrid/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/jurrid/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
]
```